# added items aren't added to cart with usage of json file and a form

Tags: php, json, string, forms

I am making a webshop for a schoolproject with php. I am currently making the shoppingcart-page and productpage but when I add a product to the cart it isn't actually added to the cart. I have spend many hours finding the solution but I couldn't fix it. I hope that anyone can help me with this issue.

this is the code of my productpage:

```
    session_start();
<section id="products">
    
    <div class="products-container">
    <?php
    // Read the JSON file
    $jsonData = file_get_contents('js/products.json');
    $products = json_decode($jsonData, true);
    
    // Initialize cart as an empty array
    $cart = array();
    
    
    // Loop through each product and display its information
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<div class="product-container">';
        echo '<div class="product-cart">';
        echo '<img class= "productimage" src="' . $product['image'] . '" alt="' . $product['name'] . '">';
        echo '<h3>' . $product['name'] . '</h3>';
        echo '<p>' . $product['description'] . '</p>';
        echo '<p class="price">Price: ' . $product['price'] . '</p>';
        echo '<form method="post" class="add-to-cart-form">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $product['id'] . '">';
        echo '<input type="number" name="quantity" value="1" min="1">';
        echo '<button type="submit" class="add-to-cart-btn">Add to Cart</button>';
        echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>

    </div>
</section>
```

As you can see I use a json file in which my products are stored. I will provide you a part of this file so you can see the contents:

```
   [
    {
        "name": "Gucci Bloom",
        "price": "€120.00",
        "image": "./pictures/gucci-Bloom.png",
        "description": "Een bloemig en houtachtig parfum voor vrouwen",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Dior Homme",
        "price": "€70.00",
        "image": "./pictures/dior-Homme.png",
        "description": "Een houtachtig en kruidig parfum voor mannen",
        "id": 2

    }
]
```

Now comes the part where I struggle, the shoppingcart-page.
This is what I currently have:

```
    <section class="productcart">
<div class="cart-card">
<table class="cart-table">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Prijs</td>
    <td>Hoeveelheid</td>
    <td>Totale prijs</td>
  </tr>


  <?php

$jsonData = file_get_contents('js/products.json');
    $products = json_decode($jsonData, true);
  $cart = array();
  foreach ($cart as $products){
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td><img class= "productimage" src="' . $product['image'] . '" alt="' . $product['name'] . '"></</td>';
  echo '<td><h3>' . $product['name'] . '</h3></td>';
  echo '<td><p class="price">' . $product['price'] . '</p></td>';
  echo '<td><p>' . $product['amount'].'</p></td>';
  echo '<td><p>' . $product['price'] * $product['amount']. '</p></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
 
  ?>

</table>
</div>
</section>
```

I hope that anyone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating the empty `$cart` array:

```
foreach ($cart as $products){...
```

But you want to iterate your `$products` array like

```
foreach ($products as $product){...
```

Comment: I only want to show the products that are added to the cart by the user. With the foreach($products as $product){...} all of the products in the json file are shown.